# Saving Array values in setter with AgularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, onsen-ui, monaca

I have a cross platform app that uses Onsen UI, Monaca and AngularJS.

I have a page that contains a number of checkboxes that are populated at runtime. I have a method that checks which checkbox is selected, and then returns that checkbox ID as was assigned to it on a database.

The view to build the list looks as follows:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item" ng-repeat="checkItemDescription in data">  
            {{checkItemDescription.checkitemdesc}}

        <label class="switch switch--list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                    class="switch__input" 
                    ng-click="toggleSelection(checkItemDescription.fleetcheckitemid)">
            <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
        </label>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

The list is built and I can detect when a switch is toggled with the  following method in my views controller

**app.js**

```
app.controller("VehicleCheckController", function($scope, $http, sharedProperties)
{
    // Get the list of checkboxes from Database here...

    // Initialising the selected items Array
    $scope.selection = [];

    // Toggle selection for a given Check Item by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(fleetCheckItemID)
    {
        var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(fleetCheckItemID);

        // Is currently selected
        if (idx > -1) 
        {
            $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
            console.log("$scope.selection: " + $scope.selection);

            // Set the Fleet Checked Selection ID to the new value
            //setFleetCheckedSelectionID($scope.selection);
            // NOT WORKING HERE
        }
        // Is newly selected
        else 
        {
            $scope.selection.push(fleetCheckItemID);
            console.log("$scope.selection: " + $scope.selection);

            // Set the Fleet Checked Selection ID to the new value
            //setFleetCheckedSelectionID($scope.selection);
            // NOT WORKING HERE
        }
    }
});
```

Then I have a service that handles the getters and setters for all the values to be shared between my various controllers. But when I try to set the values for the $scope.selection array in my service as below from my controller, I get an error saying the array is undefined.

```
// Stores the varibale $scope.fleetIDSearch form the VehicleIDController to be passed to the API URL call in VehicleCheckController
app.service('sharedProperties', function()
{
    // Initialise the Variables 
    var fleetCheckedSelectionID = [];

    return {
        // Get and set the Fleet Checked Selected ID number
        getFleetCheckedSelectionID: function()
        {
            return fleetCheckedSelectionID;
        },
        setFleetCheckedSelectionID: function(value)
        {
            fleetCheckedSelectionID = value;
        }
    };
});
```

How do I set the values that the $scope.toggleSelection method produces so I can send them to the next screen?

Comment: Is this the mistake?  You're not referencing `sharedProperties` when you called `setFleetCheckedSelectionID()`.

Comment: Yip thats exactly it. Never spotted that. If you want to make this the answer Ill mark as accepted. Thanks.